# Why are my Robolectric tests failing when using RealmResults?

Tags: java, android, mockito, realm, robolectric

I'm using Realm in my project and having a complete nightmare trying to get tests running properly. I've got everything to the point where tests pass, until you start using RealmResults to get things out of the database. The code below this is how I'm getting the results

```
private void getUser(){
    realm.beginTransaction();
    RealmResults<User> realmUsers = realm.where(User.class).findAll();
    user = realmUsers.first();
    realm.commitTransaction();
    Log.d("Test", user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName());
}
```

Simply returning all results stored in Realm. Below this is the test the full unit test.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP, manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
@PowerMockIgnore({"org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*"})
@PrepareForTest({Realm.class, RealmConfiguration.class,
        RealmQuery.class, RealmResults.class, RealmCore.class, RealmResults.class})
public class SecondActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    private SecondActivity activity;

    private RealmResults<User> realmUsers;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    // Setup Realm + Mock
    mockStatic(Realm.class);
    mockStatic(RealmConfiguration.class);
    mockStatic(RealmCore.class);
    mockStatic(RealmQuery.class);

    final Realm mockRealm = mock(Realm.class);
    doNothing().when(RealmCore.class);
    RealmCore.loadLibrary(any(Context.class));

    when(Realm.getDefaultInstance()).thenReturn(mockRealm);
    when(mockRealm.createObject(User.class)).thenReturn(new User());

    User userOne = new User("Matt", "Dunn");
    User userTwo = new User("Michael", "Stoddart");

    List<User> userList = Arrays.asList(userOne, userTwo);

    RealmQuery<User> realmQuery = mockRealmQuery();
    RealmResults<User> mockResults = mockRealmResults();

    when(mockResults.iterator()).thenReturn(userList.iterator());
    when(mockResults.size()).thenReturn(userList.size());

    when(mockResults.first()).thenReturn(userList.get(0));

    activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(SecondActivity.class);
}

    @Test
    public void checkActivityNotNull(){
        Assert.assertNotNull(activity);   
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <T extends RealmObject> RealmQuery<T> mockRealmQuery() {
        return mock(RealmQuery.class);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <T extends RealmObject> RealmResults<T> mockRealmResults() {
        return mock(RealmResults.class);
    }
}
```

However this is still throwing the following exception, even though I've followed the guide provided by realm theselves

https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/unitTestExample/src/test/java/io/realm/examples/unittesting/ExampleActivityTest.java

```
Method threw 'org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException' exception. Cannot evaluate io.realm.Realm$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$61d46d71.toString()
```

Am I mocking the RealmResults incorrectly? Or is it something entirely separate?

Edit:

The full stack trace that is provided when the test fails is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.mathewdunn.realmtest.activity.SecondActivity.getUser(SecondActivity.java:34)
    at com.example.mathewdunn.realmtest.activity.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:29)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
    at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethod(ReflectionHelpers.java:195)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:122)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:304)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter$2.runPaused(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:45)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:118)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:129)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.setup(ActivityController.java:210)
    at org.robolectric.Robolectric.setupActivity(Robolectric.java:46)
    at com.example.mathewdunn.realmtest.SecondActivityTest.setUp(SecondActivityTest.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement$1.run(PowerMockRule.java:83)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:1899)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:801)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:666)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:401)
    at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.getResult(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:69)
    at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.executeWithClassLoader(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:59)
    at org.powermock.classloading.SingleClassloaderExecutor.execute(SingleClassloaderExecutor.java:67)
    at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.execute(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:43)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement.evaluate(PowerMockRule.java:75)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:251)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

I get the NotAMock exception when debugging the test.

Edit edit:

After making some changes an alternative exception is now being thrown.

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Cannot convert type org.apache.tools.ant.Project to type org.apache.tools.ant.Project
---- Debugging information ----
message             : Cannot convert type org.apache.tools.ant.Project to type org.apache.tools.ant.Project
class               : org.apache.tools.ant.Project$1
required-type       : org.apache.tools.ant.Project$1
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement$1/outer-class/fNext/next/outer-class/outer-class/dependencyResolver/dependencyResolver/project/isLoggingMessage/outer-class
line number         : 230
class[1]            : org.apache.tools.ant.Project
class[2]            : org.robolectric.internal.dependency.MavenDependencyResolver
class[3]            : org.robolectric.internal.dependency.CachedDependencyResolver
class[4]            : org.robolectric.RobolectricGradleTestRunner
class[5]            : org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner
class[6]            : org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1
class[7]            : org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores
class[8]            : org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement
class[9]            : org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement$1
version             : not available
-------------------------------

    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:456)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:281)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:503)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:429)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:281)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:503)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:429)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:281)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:503)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:429)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:281)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:503)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:429)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:281)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:503)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:429)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:281)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:503)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:429)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:281)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:503)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:429)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:281)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:503)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:429)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:281)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:503)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:429)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:281)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1230)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1214)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1085)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1076)
    at org.powermock.classloading.DeepCloner.clone(DeepCloner.java:55)
    at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.executeWithClassLoader(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:56)
    at org.powermock.classloading.SingleClassloaderExecutor.execute(SingleClassloaderExecutor.java:67)
    at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.execute(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:43)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement.evaluate(PowerMockRule.java:75)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:265)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:191)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:56)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:157)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Cheers

Comment: Please include the entire stack trace. Somewhere `Realm.toString()` is being called.

Comment: Will edit post now @Kiskae

Comment: May I suggest you extract data layer interactions from the activity into another class? The setup of the test shows that you're testing really complex system

Comment: @EugenMartynov I usually use MVP, this was just a test project to try and get this to work, do you think using MVP would benefit me?

Comment: `Cannot convert type org.apache.tools.ant.Project to type org.apache.tools.ant.Project` this is [an error in Robolectric 3.1 and 3.2, but will be fixed in 3.3 quite soon?](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2208) Half a year ago it wasn't "soon" so you should be glad.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yeah spotted that on the robolectric repo last night, what a nightmare.

Answer (score 4):

### Incomplete mock

You're missing these lines from the [Realm test example](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/unitTestExample/src/test/java/io/realm/examples/unittesting/ExampleActivityTest.java):

```
    // The for(...) loop in Java needs an iterator, so we're giving it one that has items,
    // since the mock RealmResults does not provide an implementation. Therefore, anytime
    // anyone asks for the RealmResults Iterator, give them a functioning iterator from the
    // ArrayList of Persons we created above. This will allow the loop to execute.
    when(people.iterator()).thenReturn(personList.iterator());

    // Return the size of the mock list.
    when(people.size()).thenReturn(personList.size());
```

The explanation is in the code comment - basically RealmResults is like a Realm 'Cursor' and doesn't *contain* any data per se, but functions as a proxy for objects stored in Realm.

Take this and the fact that a mocked instance doesn't have any iterator and it becomes clear you must **redirect** your iterations over this RealmResults to a different, fully functioning `List` instance - `userList` in your case:

```
    when(mockResults.iterator()).thenReturn(userList.iterator());
    when(mockResults.size()).thenReturn(userList.size());
```

This will allow you to iterate and get the size of your mocked `RealmResults` instance.

Since you're calling `first()` on the RealmResults in your `getUser()` method, you need to **mock** this method too:

```
    when(mockResults.first()).thenReturn(userList.get(0));
```

---

Also, note that calls to `realm.beginTransaction()` and `realm.commitTransaction()` in your `getUser()` method are redundant, since you're not performing any writes. You can safely remove them, or mock them too:

```
    doCallRealMethod().when(mockRealm).beginTransaction();
    doCallRealMethod().when(mockRealm).commitTransaction();
```

Comment: I've added both of the statements you suggested and a few more and I'm now getting another null pointer on the line.


when(mockRealm.where(User.class).findAll()).thenReturn(mockResults);

Comment: @drofnnuD what is the error? Also, try removing all of the `when(realmQuery...` calls for now, since you don't need them yet - maybe you're accidentally redefining mocks with them

Comment: @drofnnuD see my edit on mocking the `realmUsers.first()` call too

Comment: I've made the edits you suggested and updated the main question, so that is the test method currently running. It still fails, throwing the same NullPointer that I posted in the main question body

Comment: @drofnnuD what about `beginTransaction()` and `commitTransaction()`? Have you tried removing those, or mocking them out with `doCallRealMethod().when(mockRealm.beginTransaction())` or `doNothing().when(mockRealm.beginTransaction())` etc?

Comment: I made some changes and have edited the main question body again, this time a new exception has been thrown, it seems like this is common place os Robolectric currently, see issue https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2208

I'm pretty stumped at this time

Comment: @drofnnuD oh, that's an interesting issue. Well then, have you tried using robolectric 3.0 instead of newer version? It looks like guys maintaining robolectric are about to push the next version with the fix also. Let me know how it goes!